# How can I use a triple slash as a delimiter with cut?

Tags: columns, cut, table

I have a table in which each entry looks something like,

```
coagulation factor VIII-associated 1 /// coagulation factor VIII-associated 2 /// coagulation factor VIII-associated 3
```

I would like to use `cut -d/// -f2 myfile.txt`, but I'm getting an error:

> cut: bad delimiter

Same case when I use single quotes or double quotes around the delimiter:

`cut -d'///' -f2 myfile.txt`

`cut -d"///" -f2 myfile.txt`

Do I have to escape the slash somehow? If so, what is the escape character for cut? Documentation doesn't seem to have that information, and I tried \.

Comment: FYI `/` is a slash. \ is a backslash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the delimiter is *anything other than one fixed character*, then `cut` is the *wrong* tool.

Use `awk` instead.

Consider this test file which has three fields:

```
$ cat file
one///two/2//two///three
```

To print the second field and only the second field:

```
$ awk -F/// '{print $2}' file
two/2//two
```

Comment: To add to this: Nothing wrong with asking here, but you should generally check the man page for the tool you are using as well.  `cut`'s manual does specify it only works with single-character delimiters.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are all right but there's also the possibility of replacing your current delimiter in order to use `cut` as you wanted such as:

```
sed "s/\/\/\//\//g" myfile.txt | cut -d/ -f2
```

Comment: using a different delimiter for `sed` (e.g. `sed 's=///=/=g'`) is easier to read because it avoids [Leaning Toothpick Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)

Comment: That just shows there are always many ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

A delimiter with [`cut`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html) is always a single character, so you can't specify "///" as a delimiter.

Instead, you'd use "/" as delimiter and count the extra fields:

```
cut -d/ -f4 myfile.txt
```

(fields 2 and 3 are the empty fields between the slashes in "///").